# When powershell is "runas" different user (different domain as well), get that user's domain, and not the logged in user's (on localhost) domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory, runas

I know how to get the domain of the user that you are logged into on windows. That's not the problem.
You can do that with `$env:USERDOMAIN` (and various other ways...)

My situation:

- I'm logged into windows as `D1Username` under `DomainOne`.
- I run cmd and do: `runas /user:DomainTwo\D2Username /netonly powershell`
- In this powershell session, I have the permissions of `D2Username`, obviously.
- When I do $env:USERDOMAIN, I get `DomainOne`, when (I would think) I should be getting `DomainTwo`.

What can I do, if anything, to get the domain of the user that is being logged into via "runas"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the resources to test this atm., but isn't this exactly what the `/netonly` parameter is for?

> /netonly   : Indicates that the user information specified is for
>   remote access only.

Source: [Runas @ TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx)

`$env:USERDOMAIN` is a local variable/run inside a local process, so it should report the domain of your local user. However, if you check the variable while remoting another computer, the `runas` credentials should be used for the network authentication (and because of that the remote session) and it would hopefully return `DomainTwo`. Try:

`Invoke-Command { $env:USERDOMAIN } -ComputerName computer2.domainone.com`

Removing the `/netonly` from the `runas`-command should give you the desired output.

Comment: That command would definitely work. I see my issue. The only reason it can't work on my machine is that there is a one-way trust from DomainOne to DomainTwo. And because of this, I now believe that there will be no solution, so long as `/netonly` is part of the code. Unfortunately, because of the one-way trust, `/netonly` is required.

Thank you very much!